# uber CURL not working when redirected to https

Tags: php, curl, uber-api

I have quite the dilemma here, while i test on the Uber sandbox using the redirect uri to `http://localhost` the function below works just fine and returns the access token and i can use all their API calls just fine with no errors

BUT when i try to change the redirect URI to an API with https the function below does not work anymore, all info are received just like for the localhost but when the CURL is executed i get

```
{"error":"invalid_request"}
```

and the following code is the function i use for this:

```
function fetchUrl($url, $code)
{

$fields = array(
    'client_id' => "MY_CLIENT_ID",
    'client_secret' => "MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
    'grant_type' => "authorization_code",
    'code' => $code
);

$fields_string = '';
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}

$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//up to this point works for HTTPS redirect uri
$result = curl_exec($ch); //the second this runs, i get
//{"error":"invalid_request"}

curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
```

for the function above:

the `$url` param is set to https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token
and the `$code` is set to what i get after oauth goes trough and returns the necessary code (the code is received in 100% of the attempts).

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is redirect URI? Where is it in your code?

Comment: redirect uri is on the uber dashboard page, when you make an app there you have to add a redirect uri, if this is set to http://localhost, it works just fine, but the second i with to send it to https://my-api.com/file_with_the_code_from_localhost it does not work anymore

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept (although not with Uber API). Likely the redirect URI must match the origin of the request. Is this the case?

Comment: yes that is the case, all information for OAUTH is returned, inside this there is a code that has to be used for all of their api calls, well this code is not returned unless i point the redirect to my localhost

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here,`$code` should only be used once to generate the `access_token` and the `refresh_token` that will be later used to refresh the `access_token`.

My mistake was to try to generate the token every time i used a method from uber, that is not needed, if you follow the steps from this link 
https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token 
you can be sure it will work just fine!